# HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() fails without error inside DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, httprequest, hmac

I'm trying to implement HMAC security for an API. Everything works fine until I try to post a file.

The HMAC solution can be found here - https://github.com/gavinharriss/WebAPI.HMAC - it's a fork from the original to allow GET requests as well as POST requests.

The code to attach a file:

```
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
requestContent.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);
```

if I immediately call `HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` there is no issue, the byte array is available.

However, the HMAC `HttpClient` ([HMACHttpClient](https://github.com/gavinharriss/WebAPI.HMAC/blob/master/WebAPI.HMAC/Http/HMACHttpClient.cs)) implements a `DelegatingHandler` ([HMACDelegatingHandler](https://github.com/gavinharriss/WebAPI.HMAC/blob/master/WebAPI.HMAC/Http/HMACDelegatingHandler.cs)) in order to attach the HMAC header to requests.

In the [HMACDelegatingHandler](https://github.com/gavinharriss/WebAPI.HMAC/blob/master/WebAPI.HMAC/Http/HMACDelegatingHandler.cs) the request is passed along as a `HttpRequestMessage` from which the `HttpRequestMessage.Content` property is used in a helper to build the HMAC signature.

When building the signature, the following code is called from a [helper class](https://github.com/gavinharriss/WebAPI.HMAC/blob/master/WebAPI.HMAC/Crypto/HMACHelper.cs):

```
private static async Task<byte[]> ComputeHash(HttpContent httpContent)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = null;
        if (httpContent != null)
        {
            var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); // <-- Fails here
            if (content.Length != 0)
            {
                hash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

When stepping through the code the `var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` line is hit, then nothing, no error. The requests just seems to go poof but everything is still running and the `HttpClient` request never gets sent.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having tested this with various sizes of file, I found the issue arose when files got around the 50,000 byte mark.

This post provided a solution: [HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync causes request to hang (or other strange behaviours)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797236/httpcontent-readasstringasync-causes-request-to-hang-or-other-strange-behaviour).

If you replace erroring line in HMACHelper (line 66):

```
var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

with this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
await httpContent.CopyToAsync(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var content = ms.ToArray();
```

It should stop hanging.